# Соединить 2 массива в 1 одномерный

Tags: java

Стоит задача соединить 2 массива(отсортированных) в 1, причем таким образом, чтобы он уже сразу был отсортирован. То-есть если на вход подаются массивы {0, 2} и {1, 3}, то на выходе должен получиться массив {0, 1, 2, 3}

```
      public static int[] mergeArrays(int[] a1, int[] a2) {
    if (a1 == null)
        return a2;
    if (a2 == null)
        return a1;
    int[] r = new int[a1.length + a2.length];
    for (int i = 0, a1Index = 0, a2Index = 0; i < r.length; ) {
        while (a1Index < a1.length && a1[a1Index] < a2[a2Index]) {
            r[i] = a1[a1Index];
            a1Index++;
            i++;
        }
        r[i] = a2[a2Index];
        a2Index++;
        i++;
    }
    return r;
}
```

У меня почему то выпригивает из границ массива.

Comment: Нужно использовать именно массивы идти и коллекции подойдут?

Comment: массивы...
но проблему я уже нашел... пробую исправить

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как-то так:

```
    public static int[] mergeArrays(int[] a1, int[] a2) {
    int[] r = new int[a1.length + a2.length];
    int a1Ind = 0;
    int a2Ind = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < r.length;i++ ) {
        if (a1Ind == a1.length) {
            System.arraycopy(a2,a2Ind,r, i, r.length-i);
            break;
        }
        if (a2Ind == a2.length) {
            System.arraycopy(a1, a1Ind, r, i, r.length-i);
            break;
        }
        if (a1[a1Ind]<=a2[a2Ind]){
            r[i]=a1[a1Ind];
            a1Ind++;
        }else {
            r[i]=a2[a2Ind];
            a2Ind++;
        }
    }
    return r;
}
```

Вроде работает...
если кто зайдет и предложит лучше вариант, буду благодарен.

Answer (score 1):

У меня получилось такое решение:

```
private static int[] merge(int[] firstArray, int[] secondArray) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(firstArray);
    Objects.requireNonNull(secondArray);

    int[] result = new int[firstArray.length + secondArray.length];
    int firstIndex = 0;
    int secondIndex = 0;
    int index = 0;

    while (firstIndex < firstArray.length && secondIndex < secondArray.length)
        if (firstArray[firstIndex] <= secondArray[secondIndex])
            result[index++] = firstArray[firstIndex++];
        else
            result[index++] = secondArray[secondIndex++];

    if (index == result.length)
        return result;

    while (firstIndex < firstArray.length)
        result[index++] = firstArray[firstIndex++];
    while (secondIndex < secondArray.length)
        result[index++] = secondArray[secondIndex++];

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Java 8

```
int[] a1 = {0,2,5,8,9};
int[] a2 = {1,4,3,7,6};
int[] result = IntStream.concat(Arrays.stream(a1),Arrays.stream(a2)).sorted().toArray();

for (int i : result) {
    System.out.print(i + " ");
}
```

0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

Comment: Благодарю за ответ. Учту себе на будущее.
Но у меня я так понял в условии задачи нельзя было пользоваться сортировкой, нужно ыло сразу раскидывать елементы в массив так, чтобы его не нужно было пересортирововать.